# Convert binary to hex to decimal

Tags: c, binary, hex, decimal

I have the binary number 1010 1011. I know that this is AB in hex and I know that A = 10 and B = 11 in decimal. But how do I get from 10 and 11 in decimal to the final number of 171?

With hex I would do

```
             A            B
0xAB = (10 * 16^1) + (11 * 16^0) = 171
```

Can I do something similar with the decimal numbers to go from 10 and 11 to 171? Basically, I'm just looking for a fast way to convert any binary number without a calculator.

Comment: I'm using C for these things.

Comment: Excellent, so do you have code to show us for how you're trying to do your conversions?

Comment: how do you store the number 1010 1011?

Comment: [C convert hex to decimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676763/c-convert-hex-to-decimal-format) or better yet [Converting dec/binary](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2548374/1243316)

Comment: @BradRem Ehm.. I'm not actually looking for a library or anything, I'm simply learning about binary/hex and decimal because I'm new to bitwise operations and I'm trying to make sense of everything.

Comment: @perreal Not sure if it is compiler dependent, but you can store it in C using 0b10101011. E.g. unsigned char myByte = 0b10101011;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a much easier way than A × 16 + B.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to do, and the the language you are using, you could use the shift-left operator and add the values together.

In C++:

```
unsigned short val_a = (0x1010 << 4);
unsigned short val_b = 0x1011;
unsigned short result = val_a + val_b;
```

The result is still an unsigned short int.

Answer (score 0):

In C you can shift instead if multiplication to get AB from A and B:

```
int number = A << 4 + B;
```

if you store A as 1010 (decimal) and B as 1011, you can convert:

```
int bin2dec(unsigned int s){ 
  int v, p;
  for (v = 0, p = 1; s > 0; s=s>>1) { v = v+p*(s%2); v++; p*=2;}
  return v;
}

int number = bin2dec(A) << 4 + bin2dec(B);
```

Comment: Following your steps precisely, I get  `number = 2040;` or 0x7f8.