# I dont know what is wrong with this program. it's supposed to convert binary to decimal in c

Tags: c, string

well this program is supposed to convert a binary number to decimal. im new to c and im not very confident in coding C. tried and coded this program but doesnt run properly. and I have no idea what part is wrong here. need some help to complete this program.
thanks

```
binaryToDecimal(char str[]) {
    for(int i = strlen(str)-i; i>=0; i--) {
        if(str[i] == 48 || str[i] == 49) {
            int tmp = pow(2, counter);
            int sum= str[i]*tmp;
            counter++;
            answer += sum;
        } else if(str[i]>49 || str[i]<48) {
            printf("error");
        }
    }
    printf("%d", &answer);
}
```

Comment: this may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852917/convert-binary-to-hex-to-decimal

Comment: What's the type of answer?

Comment: Please explain *doesn't run properly*.  What input do you give it? What output do you expect? What output did you actually get?

Comment: "doesn't run properly" is not a problem description that is useful. What exactly does "doesn't run properly" mean? In what way is it not proper? If you want us to help you, you need to be *specific about the problem you're having*. After all, you know what it is, or you wouldn't be posting here for help. Why not explain it to us so we know too?

Answer (score 2):

This phrase doesn't make sense:

```
int i = strlen(str)-i;
```

`i` hasn't been initialized yet, but you're using it in the expression!

I believe you meant:

```
int i = strlen(str)-1;   // ONE ... not I
```

Comment: `answer` is too not initialized.

Answer (score 2):

`str[i]` is a character, either '1' or '0' which as you have it is equal to 48 and 49 as integers. So you want to convert them to 1 and 0 them do the multiplication.

```
sum = (str[i] - 48) * tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all variables have been initialised to sensible values and `str` holds the input. The following code should work, although it is not particularly efficient.
You can use `'0'` and `'1'` instead of more obscure `48` and `49`.

```
for (i = strlen(str)-1, j = 0; i >= 0; --i, ++j) { 

   if (str[i] != '0' && str[i] != '1') {
       printf("ERROR: unxepected input\n");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   if (str[i] == '1')
       sum += pow(2, j);
}
```

when printing the result provide the value and not it's address, e.g.

```
printf("%d\n", sum);  // (!) not &sum
```