# Converting hex to dec C++

Tags: c++, hex, decimal

Convert to hex:

```
cout << hex << int(x) << endl;
```

How to convert conversely, from hex to dec?

Enter hex number simple:

```
cin >> hex >> x;
```

Comment: Integers are printed as decimal by default. Could be your problem is actually _inputting_ hexadecimal numbers? I.e. as in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031159/converting-hexadecimal-to-decimal

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `std::dec` [IO manipulator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip):

```
std::cout << std::dec << int(x) << endl;
```

Note that this is only necessary if you have previously used `std::hex` or other means to manipulate the base of `std::cout`. Otherwise you need take no action: the default for an `int` is decimal.

Answer (score 3):

*Don't* use the `std::hex` manipulator?

```
std::cout << int(x) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Ok. How to enter hext number in console? Using char or int?

Comment: @user2605734 Did you look at the question I linked? Doesn't it answer that?

Comment: @user2605734 `char` is for single characters, `int` is for normal integers (within its specified range)