# concatenating individual characters and converting to a combined decimal in c++

Tags: c++, hex, decimal, concatenation

I have a sensor that stores the recorded information as a .pcap file. I have managed to load the file into an unsigned char array. the sensor stores information in a unique format. For instance representing an angle of 290.16, it stores the information as binary equivalent of 0x58 0x71.

what I have to do to get the correct angle is that concatenate 0x71 and 0x58 then convert the resultant hex value into a decimal divide it by 100 and then store it for further analysis.

My current approach is this:

```
//all header files are included

main
{
 unsigned char data[50]; //I actually have the data loaded in this from a file
 data[40] = 0x58;  
 data[41] = 0x71;
 // The above maybe incorrect. What i am trying to imply is that if i use the statement
 // printf("%.2x %.2x", data[40],data[41]); 
 // the resultant output you see on screen is 
 // 58 71

 //I get the decimal value i wanted using the below statement
 float gar = hex2Dec(dec2Hex(data[41])+dec2Hex(data[40]))/100.0;
}
```

hex2Dec and dec2Hex are my own functions.

```
unsigned int hex2Dec (const string Hex)
{
    unsigned int DecimalValue = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Hex.size(); ++i)
    {
        DecimalValue = DecimalValue * 16 + hexChar2Decimal (Hex[i]);
    }

    return DecimalValue;
}


string dec2Hex (unsigned int Decimal)
{
    string Hex = "";

    while (Decimal != 0)
    {
        int HexValue = Decimal % 16;

        // convert deimal value to a Hex digit
        char HexChar = (HexValue <= 9 && HexValue >= 0 ) ? 
            static_cast<char>(HexValue + '0' ) : static_cast<char> (HexValue - 10 + 'A');

        Hex = HexChar + Hex;
        Decimal = Decimal /16;
    }

    return Hex;
}

int hexChar2Decimal (char Ch)
{
    Ch= toupper(Ch); //Change the chara to upper case
    if (Ch>= 'A' && Ch<= 'F')
    {
        return 10 + Ch- 'A';
    }
    else
        return Ch- '0';
}
```

The pain is that I have to do this conversion billions of time which really slows down the process. Is there any other efficient way to deal with this case?

A matlab code that my friend developed for a similar sensor, took him 3 hours to extract data that was worth only 1 minute of real time. I really need it to be as fast as possible.

Comment: @Nabla Thank you for pointing it out. I did get them mixed up. I have edited the question to reflect the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell this does the same as

```
float gar = ((data[45]<<8)+data[44])/100.0;
```

For:

```
unsigned char data[50];
data[44] = 0x58;  
data[45] = 0x71;
```

the value of `gar` will be `290.16`.

Explanation:

It is not necessary to convert the value of an integer to a string to get the hex value, because decimal, hexadecimal, binary, etc. are only different representations of the same value. `data[45]<<8` shifts the value of `data[45]` eight bits to the left. Before the operation is performed the type of the operand is promoted to `int` (except for some unusual implementations where it might be `unsigned int`), so the new data type should be large enough to not overflow. Shifting eight bits to the left is equivalent to shifting 2 digits to the left in hexadecimal representation. So the result is `0x7100`. Then the value of `data[44]` is added to that and you get `0x7158`. The result of type `int` is then cast to `float` and divided by `100.0`.

In general `int` might be too small to apply the shift operation without shifting the sign if it is only 16-bit long. If you want to cover that case then explicitly cast to `unsigned int`:

```
float gar = (((unsigned int)data[45]<<8)+data[44])/100.0;
```

Comment: I knew they were the same at the bit level, but did not know about the `<<` operator and that using this operator will promote the car to `unsigned int`. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @bvk Fixed an error I made, it is (in most cases) `int` not `unsigned int`.

Comment: If it is promoted to int, then I will not be able to have values like 35965 right (which means angle is 359.65)? i mean imagine, what i am getting here is basically angles with a precision of 0.01. Should this not cause a problem if the implementation is an int, because int cannot hold values like 35000

Comment: @bvk Indeed that might be a problem if `int` is 16-bit wide in your implementation, that's why I added the last part that guarantees that `unsigned int` is used, which has to be able to hold large enough values on all platforms. But in many cases `int` is 32-bit wide anyway. You can also use `uint_fast16_t` from `<cstdint>`. This type is also unsigned and guaranteed to be at least 16-bit wide.

Answer (score 0):

In here [C convert hex to decimal format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676763/c-convert-hex-to-decimal-format), Emil H
posted some sample code that looks very similar to what you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *hex_value_string = "deadbeef";
    unsigned int out;

    sscanf(hex_value_string, "%x", &out);

    printf("%o %o\n", out, 0xdeadbeef);
    printf("%x %x\n", out, 0xdeadbeef);

    return 0;
}
```

Your conversion functions don't look particularly efficient, so hopefully this is faster.